# Are there any significant differences between the censored Talmud and the uncensored Talmud?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, manuscripts

Are there any significant differences between the censored Talmud and the uncensored Talmud?
And are there tools to study this topic?

Comment: Yes. Thanks
@shmosel

Comment: @harounezeraib why do you have a Nazi tank commander as your profile icon?

Comment: It was without intention , I changed it
@Deuteronomy